# Easiest way to temporarily store key-value pairs in a form using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I temporarily store an array of string values most elegantly in a form?

I have a form, where a user can edit an article - and add tags, which are simply string values.

I don't want to persist it until the user actually saves the entire article, so I need to be able to temporarily ...:

- Display the list of selected tags
- Add a tag to the list
- Remove a tag from the list
- Submit the list of values when I save the form

I could store everything in just a comma-separated hidden field, but it seems ugly, and I would prefer something stronger typed.

What is the right way to do this? Pointers to examples very welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JQuery provides the [`data`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data) method for precisely these situations! It works directly with native JavaScript objects, so no need to mess about with comma separated lists - just use an array or object. Perhaps something like this will get you on the right track.

```
// initialize existing tags
$('#form').data('tags', { foo: true, bar: true });

// add a new tag
$('#form').data('tags').baz = true;

// remove an existing tag
$('#form').data('tags').bar = false;

$('#form').data('tags');
// { foo: true, bar: false, baz: true }
```

Having removed tags remain in the object as `false` will help you see which tags need unassigning server-side; not necessary but potentially useful to you.

If you would rather the removed values were removed completely from the object, use the `delete` construct.

```
// remove an existing tag
delete $('#form').data('tags').bar;
```

---

Edit: In an attempt to address your comments on this answer and give you some ideas:

```
<ul class="tags">
    <li>
        <span class="tag-name">foo</span>
        <a href="#" class="tag-remove">remove</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And your JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#form .tag-remove').click(function(e) {
        // update the tag data
        var tag = $(this).siblings('.tag-name').text();
        $('#form').data('tags')[tag] = false;

        // remove the tag element
        $(this).parent().remove();

        return false;
    });
});
```

There will be more of course - this does not handle the initialization of the form's tag data, the addition of new tags, or the submitting of tags to the server - but hopefully it will nudge you in the right direction :)

Comment: Very useful! :)

Followup: Maybe you could add an example of how you modify a value based on its key? 

function remove(key) {
            $('#form').data('tags')....???
        }

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but does that addition answer your question?

Comment: I want to write a function I can call to remove a key from the tags-array. So I can put this html in each item, when I display them: <li>foo<a href="remove('foo')">remove</a></li>.